# How to handle the selected item in AutoCompleteTextView dropdown in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, dropdown, spinner

I have a dropdown list in a fragment that I would like to get the item selected and work with it. How can I achieve this?

```
       val states = resources.getStringArray(R.array.states)
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.state_drop_down_item, states)
        binding.addAddressFragmentStateAutoComplete.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected item of AutoCompleteTextView dropdown you have to set `onItemClickListener` to AutoCompleteTextView like below:

```
addAddressFragmentStateAutoComplete.onItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
    val item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
}
```